# How to get git diff --name-only to be in sync with git pull

Tags: git, diff, line

When I do 
git diff --name-only
it always shows one filename, but I want it to be an empty output. I would like to get 
git diff to be in sync with git pull, so when git pull says my project is up to date, then git diff should show no changes. How do I do this? I just want the output of git diff to be empty. I have tried deleting the file, stash it, check it out again, but nothing helps. The difference between the files are the line endings. Also when I add that path to .gitignore it still shows the file when I do git diff....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once a file is under version control, ignoring it doesn't work. You can ignore untracked files only. If you don't want to delete the file, fix the line endings and take a look at [Dealing with line endings](https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings).

Line endings and encoding are common problems when different platforms are used in the same project. Add a `.gitattributes` file, as described in the GitHub article. Be aware that setting the line endings in git's configuration is not enough, you will have to fix the files yourself or use the suggested auto-fix in the article.

Comment: I did
git rm --cached FILENAME
and then maybe like this
http://www.arlocarreon.com/blog/git/untrack-files-in-git-repos-without-deleting-them/
It works now anyway. Thank you